# Explanation of top (CPU usage)

Tags: linux, debian

My server has been steady at about 2-3%, but today the CPU usage has raised to about 25%

When I run `top` in command line this is what I see.. user is still low about 1.3% and the same with system about 1.2% but then I look at `wa`.. 16.1% !?

What is `wa` and why is it suddenly so high?!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page, wa is:

```
wa  --  iowait
Amount of time the CPU has been waiting for I/O to complete.
```

Comment: Could you explain what it is

Comment: The CPU is waiting for the disk to give it some data to work on. You should look into what the disk is doing.

A more in depth answer is here, including tools that can be used to look into what the disk is doing: http://serverfault.com/questions/12679/can-anyone-explain-precisely-what-iowait-is

Comment: I don't think it is only disk, but any IO device which blocks a process from continuing.